# Difference between different ways of writing IF Exists?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

I just want to test if something exists in a table

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ta WHERE ca = 'abc') PRINT 'YES'
IF EXISTS (SELECT ca FROM ta WHERE ca = 'abc') PRINT 'YES'
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ta WHERE ca = 'abc') PRINT 'YES'
IF EXISTS (SELECT (1) FROM ta WHERE ca = 'abc') PRINT 'YES'
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ta WHERE ca = 'abc') PRINT 'YES'
```

Do they have any differences in result/side effect/performance (no matter how tiny)?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Absolutely no difference** - the `IF EXISTS(...)` will only check for existence of rows based on the `WHERE` clause in your statement.

Everything else in the statement is irrelevant - doesn't make any difference whether you use `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1` or or `SELECT TOP 1 *`. Even using `SELECT * ....` does **NOT** select all columns from the table - it again just checks for existence of the data based on the `WHERE` clause.

All five queries have **exactly** the same execution plan

Comment: Thank you! So you are implying that those queries do have some differences when they are not paired with IF EXISTS?

Comment: @user1589188: sure - if you have a "stand-alone" `SELECT *` - that's bad because you get (a) all columns (do you really need ***all*** columns???), (b) your not specifying which columns you want (might get a nasty surprise if a BLOB column like an image is added at some point) and so forth. When not inside an `IF EXISTS(..)` I advocate to **never** use `SELECT *` (definitely not in your production code) - always use **explicit** lists of columns, and grab as few columns as you really really need.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, the execution plan seems to be same.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow! Great input! Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Habib which tool have you used for the visualization purpose and is there are some more you can recommend.